# Quais as melhores práticas de representar SQL dentro de código PHP?

Tags: php, sql

Programo PHP juntamente com SQL (principalmente MySQL) há um bom tempo, já tenho uma certa experiência, entretanto nunca achei uma boa solução para isso: qual a melhor forma de inserir SQL dentro de código PHP?

Normalmente o que o pessoal faz é inserir o código entre aspas, por exemplo:

```php
$sql = "
     SELECT *
     FROM usuarios u
     ORDER BY u.nome";
```

Entretanto, para fins de logging não fica muito interessante, pois o SQL aparece da forma como está no código. Para corrigir isso, uma solução seria concatenarmos sucessivas strings:

```php
$sql = 
     "SELECT * ".
     "from usuarios u ".
     "ORDER BY u.nome";
```

Porém, é pouco prático e sujeito a erros.

Outra sintaxe que já vi mas acho meio bizarra é HEREDOC ou NOWDOC:

```php
$sql = <<<EOT
    SELECT *
    from usuarios u
    ORDER BY u.nome
EOT;
```

Já pensei também em colocar as SQL em arquivos separados, com seus devidos placeholders (para parâmetros, ao usá-los com Doctrine2, por exemplo), mas não sei se é uma prática comum.

Notem que não estou perguntando, por exemplo, se deveria usar SQL plano, DQL ou o QueryBuilder; a pergunta é sobre estilos ao representar uma SQL "pura" no meio de um código PHP :)

Enfim, quais as melhores práticas em representar SQL dentro de código PHP?

Comment: Atenham-se a critérios objetivos. Gosto pessoal não cabe uma plataforma de **perguntas** e **respostas**. Se houver muitas respostas apenas expondo o gosto, acarretará no fechamento da pergunta por ser "apenas baseado em opiniões".  http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective

Comment: Muito bom, não havia visto esse texto. De fato a pergunta é muito mais subjetiva do que objetiva, e tenderia àquelas discussões que "não acabam nunca". Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada forma tem vantagens e desvantagens.

## Arquivo texto

Na época em que estava desenvolvendo um framework em PHP, cogitei muito a possibilidade de armazenar as *queries* em arquivos texto.

Isso reforçaria a separação de conceitos, isto é, não queria me preocupar com a sintaxe do PHP misturada com SQL.

Entretanto, após considerar o impacto de *ler e processar* os arquivos, desisti da ideia.

## Arquivo PHP separado

Utilizei esta abordagem em um projeto e achei bem interessante. Cada classe possuía um respectivo arquivo PHP com as *queries* em strings. O `heredoc` é uma representaçãop interessante nessa abordagem.

A vantagem é que você consegue ter uma visão geral das *queries*, facilitando a refatoração do SQL, e seu código fica mais limpo. A desvantagem é que às vezes você precisa ficar alternando de arquivo várias vezes para ver o conteúdo das variáveis.

## *Queries* inline

Hoje eu evito ao máximo, em qualquer linguagem colocar as *queries* diretamente dentro de uma função ou método.

Primeiro porque com SQLs distribuídos no meio do código, se a tabela muda, frequentemente esqueço de atualizar uma das *queries* "perdidas" em arquivos e métodos.

Segundo, porque, embora até funcione bem para *queries* muito simples, em geral acaba "estragando" a formatação do código e "quebrando" o fluxo do mesmo, atrapalhando sua leitura.

## Representando o SQL em String

Para representar o SQL numa String PHP, eu evitaria ao máximo a forma que concatena linha a linha. Isso é pedir por uma tendinite.

Usando aspas em várias linhas, não fica tão feio se não usar tabulação. Exemplo:

```php
<?php 
$sql = "
SELECT *
FROM usuarios u
ORDER BY u.nome";
```

O único problema da String acima é uma quebra de linha no início.

Já o formato `heredoc` me parece o mais interessante. Primeiro porque não há problema da quebra de linha ou de formatação. Além disso, ele permite copiar e colar a *query* facilmente, o que considero importante, já que faço isso frequentemente durante o desenvolvimento.

Depois que você acostumar um pouco com ele não vai parecer tão estranho. ;)

Por outro lado, como mencionado na própria pergunta, existe ainda o formato `Nowdoc`. Segundo a documentação, ele funciona como aspas simples, onde o conteúdo não é analisado e, portanto,  variáveis não são interpoladas. O uso de `Nowdoc` é interessante pois evita processamento desnecessário em Strings "constantes", isto é, que não tem variáveis PHP dentro.

## Considerações gerais

Adotar um padrão de onde armazenar as *queries* facilita o entendimento do sistema pelos desenvolvedores e evita a introdução de *bugs*, já que não há SQLs esparramados pelo código.

Comment: No final das contas ababei optando pela sintaxe NOWDOC (http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc), em que nenhuma análise é feita na string, interessante para uma query SQL que conta apenas com placeholders. Obrigado!

Comment: @rodrigorigotti Tem razão, havia esquecido de mencionar o Nowdoc. Ele vai melhorar sensivelmente o desempenho. De qualquer forma, editei a resposta para não ficar faltando.

Answer (score 1):

Eu usava de forma tabulada normal, porem hoje tenho utilizado muito a classe "dibi" ele é um wrapper e layer abbstraction de banco de dados, extremamente potente, leve e útil...

http://dibiphp.com

A classe também suporta programação fluente, o que é extremamente prático para dar manutenção, por exemplo:

Meu select normal seria assim:

> $sql = "
>        SELECT *
>        FROM usuarios u
>        ORDER BY u.nome";

No dibi de modo fluente vc pode usar assim:

> $resultado =
>   dibi::select('*')->from('usuarios')->as('u')->orderBy('u.nome')->fetchAll();

Também há como fazer de um outro jeito bem prático, assim:

> $resutlado = dibi::query('SELECT * FROM [usuarios] AS [u] ORDER BY
>   [u].[nome]')

Nota que na segunda vez botei entre colchetes porque o postgree utiliza as colunas como "u"."nome" então o dibi verifica se vc está usando PGSQL ou MYSQL já que ele é abstração e se for mysql ele tira os [] se for PGSQL ele converte os [] para ""

Enfim ele é prático e posso mudar o meu db de PGSQL para MYSQL ou SQL Server ou outros sem ter que mudar praticamente nada de código...

Acho que vale a pena vc conferir a classe é muito boa... Forte abraço.

Comment: Conforme eu havia dito acima, na maioria das vezes eu uso um approach mais orientado a objetos, mas uma vez ou outra acabo tendo que usar SQL puro mesmo. Para a abstração, faço mais ou menos o que você sugeriu, porém com o Doctrine2. Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Eu sempre utilizo esse método:

```
$sql = "
 SELECT *
 FROM usuarios u
 ORDER BY u.nome";
```

Acho mais fácil e menos propenso a erro!

Answer (score 0):

Creio que não hajá uma forma mais correta, costumo escrever em uma mesma linha mesmo, alguns organizam em várias para facilitar a leitura, mas caso o tema seja organização eu diria que gosto da forma que se escreve em Zend, assim você escreve orientado a objeto e no final o resultado é uma query normal em uma unica linha:

[Exemplo](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html)

Comment: Só que para usar você teria que usar o framework claro...

Comment: EU já vi essa sintaxe, includivo uso bastante no Doctrine2, mas de vez em quando acabo tento que usar queries queries "puras", por isso a pergunta :)